# Why multiprocessing does not change values of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to perform a set of operations on a matrix of elements of the same class. All those operations are defined in the class I wrote down and may use operations defined in other classes of the same file.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

class TestClass():
    a=[]
    b=[]
    c=[]

    def run(self,string):
        self.a=string
        print(self.a)

if __name__=='__main__':
    #define the matrix of variables
    var=[TestClass]*10    
    for i in range(10):
       var[i]=[TestClass]*10
       for k in range(10):
           var[i][k]=TestClass()

    #do calculations       
    pool=mp.Pool(processes=3)    
    pool.starmap_async(TestClass.run, [(var[i][k], 'ciao') for i in range(10) for k in range(10)])
    pool.close()

    #print results
    [print(var[i][k].a) for i in range(10) for k in range(10)]
```

I expected to have all `var[x].a` set to `'ciao'`, but they are all `[]` .

What I missed?

Comment: as I know it use `pickle` to send data to process so process uses copy of data from main thread. And it use `return` to send result. But it will not put it back to `var`. You have to run `result = pool.starmap_async()` and next `result.get()`

Answer (score 0):

As I know `multiprocessing` uses `pickle` to send data to process so process uses copy of data from main process. And it uses return to send result but it will not put it back to `var`.

You have to run processes

```
 result = pool.starmap_async(...)
```

and next get results

```
 result.get()
```

But it will never change values in `var`. You would have to copy values froom `results` to `var`.

---

In code I use matrix 3x3 to better see results. `run` uses `return self` to send back class.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class TestClass():
    a = []
    def run(self, value):
        self.a = value
        return self # return all class

if __name__=='__main__':
    # define the matrix of variables
    var = []
    for i in range(3):
        row = []
        for k in range(3):
            row.append(TestClass())
        var.append(row)

    # display matrix to check if IDs are differnt
    for row in var:
        for item in row:
            print(item)
        print('-')
    print('---')

    # define the matrix of variables
    #var = [[TestClass() for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
    #
    # display matrix to check if IDs are differnt
    #for row in var:
    #    for item in row:
    #        print(item)
    #    print('-')
    #print('---')

    #run processes
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=3)    
    result = pool.starmap_async(TestClass.run, [(item, 'ciao') for item in row for row in var])
    pool.close()

    # get results
    print('result.get:', result.get())

    # display results
    for item in result.get():
        print('item.a:', item.a)
```

Comment: Thanks furas. 
Now python gives me this message  
--- 
Exception in thread Thread-12:
 [...] 
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'TestClass' on <module 'main' from 'C:\\Users\\Fil\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\spyder\\utils\\ipython\\start_kernel.py'> 
--- 
and it crashes when running result.get().

It does not yet work. Can you help me?

Comment: if you have new problem then use button `Ask Question` and you will have more space to show code. Code in comment is unreadable. And other users will also read your question - they may have better solutions.

Comment: The problem that I found is related to the code you posted: I ran the code but there is a problem with the fact that the class returns itself. My interpreter says that it cannot get attribute 'TestClass'. Do I have to import some module I did not?

Comment: It also crashes when have to run result.get().

Comment: do you run code in one file ? You can use `return self.a` in `TestClass` and then `print('item:', item)` instead of `print('item.a:', item.a)` in main code

Comment: Yes, it runs in one file. By using `return self.a` it works, but I need to return all the class in my real case.

Comment: then create new question and add code from real case.

Comment: do you run it from spyder ? Did you try to run it without spyder - directly in cmd.exe `python script.py `?

Comment: THANKS! Yeah, it works now! I just launch it from windows prompt. I have no issues returning the class TestClass! I added a loop to substitute the old `var` matrix with the new ones to reach my goal. It is probably not the best, but  it is what I looked for!